Ошибка при импортирован и модуля
С помощью pip установил модуль aiogram, но при импортировании получаю ошибку 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram'. При попытке установки повторно, получаю ошибку о том что метаданные не совпадают. Подскажите как бороться?

возможные дубликаты

1 - проверьте, что устанавливаете в то же самое виртуальное окружение (в тот же интерпретатор), которым запускаете. 2 - про метаданные приведите полный текст ошибки.
